# Enroll Fingerprint with standard ISO/IEC 19794-2 in Android

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api, iso-19794

I'm developing a Digital Signment with authentication for fingerprint. I'm analazing use the scanner integrated of cellphone for enroll the fingerprint. But, I have to handle fingerprint with Standar ISO/IEC 19794-2. And I don't know how Android handle the minutiae data when you take the fingerprint. Do we know if it is posible to do this?

Comment: See section _7.3.10. Fingerprint Sensor_ [in the Android CDD](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd), and the [Android Fingerprint HAL guidelines](https://source.android.com/security/authentication/fingerprint-hal). If it's not specified there how the data should be stored, then you probably can't count on it being standardized.

Comment: And in case you were asking because you want to process the data, then the simple answer is: You can't (your app won't have access to the data in any form).